# I have clearly indicated that if a tweet has already been favorited, skip it but the program keeps crushing

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

Here is the code but the program keeps crushing after favoriting a few names:

```
def favs():
    time_line = api.home_timeline(count=50)
    for tweet in time_line:
        if tweet.user.name != "flaxemsystem":
             if tweet.favorited:
                print(f"liking {tweet.author.name}")
                api.create_favorite(tweet.id)
                time.sleep(2)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should change the

```
if tweet.favorited:
```

line as

```
if not tweet.favorited:
```

So the finalized code could be:

```
def favs():
    time_line = api.home_timeline(count=50)
    for tweet in time_line:
        if tweet.user.name != "flaxemsystem":
             if not tweet.favorited:
                print(f"liking {tweet.author.name}")
                api.create_favorite(tweet.id)
                time.sleep(2)
```